# How to use an internal method in a Objective-C category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

Trying to extend the capabilities from a open source project, I wrote a category for add a new method. In this new method, the category needs to access to an internal method from the original class, but the compiler says that it can't find the method (of course, is internal). Is there any way to expose this method for the category?

**EDIT**

I don't want to modify the original code, so I don't want to declare the internal method in the original class header file.

**The code**

In the original class implementation file (.m), I have this method implementation:

```
+(NSDictionary*) storeKitItems
{
  return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
          [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
           @"MKStoreKitConfigs.plist"]];
}
```

In the category, I want to add this method:

```
- (void)requestProductData:(NSArray *(^)())loadIdentifierBlock
{
    NSMutableArray *productsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *consumables = [[[MKStoreManager storeKitItems] objectForKey:@"Consumables"] allKeys];
    NSArray *nonConsumables = [[MKStoreManager storeKitItems] objectForKey:@"Non-Consumables"];
    NSArray *subscriptions = [[[MKStoreManager storeKitItems] objectForKey:@"Subscriptions"] allKeys];
    if(loadIdentifierBlock != nil) [productsArray addObjectsFromArray:loadIdentifierBlock()];
    [productsArray addObjectsFromArray:consumables];
    [productsArray addObjectsFromArray:nonConsumables];
    [productsArray addObjectsFromArray:subscriptions];
    self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [self.productsRequest start];
}
```

In every line in which I call `storeKitItems`compiler says: *Class method "+storeKitItems" not found ...*

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama what did you mean with "correctly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category has no access to the private methods of a class. It's no different than trying to call those methods from any other class. At least if you call the private method directly. Since Objective-C is so dynamic, you can call private methods (which is a bad idea) using other means such as using `performSelector` or with `NSInvocation`.

Again, this is a bad idea. An update to the implementation of the class could break your category.

Edit: Now that there is code posted -

Since the `+storeKitItems` method is not declared in the .h file, no category or other class can access the private method.

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama Sure it is. It's about methods that are not declared public in the .h file.

Comment: You can call "private" methods directly (Objective-C doesn't really have the notion of public and private methods) -- you'll just get a compiler warning if it's not declared (e.g., in a header file).

Comment: @rmaddy I can declare the current internal method in the original header, but again, an update to the project can break the category.

Comment: @LuisEspinoza As I said, you can workaround the issue (but I advise against it) by calling the method indirectly like I stated in my answer.

Comment: @mipadi I guess that's true. I've been using the "treat warnings as errors" compiler flag exclusively for years so I forget that this is really just a warning and not an error. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is trivial, make a forward declaration of the method.

Unfortunately, in obj-c, every method declaration must be inside `@interface`, so you can make it work in your category `.m` file with another internal category, e.g.

```
@interface MKStoreManager (CategoryInternal)
   + (NSDictionary*)storeKitItems;
@end
```

No implementation is needed, this only tells the compiler the method is somewhere else, similarly to `@dynamic` with properties.

If you are only interested in removing the warning, you can also just cast the class to `id`, the following should work, too:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [(id) [MKStoreManager class] storeKitItems];
```

However, my favorite solution is to do it a bit differently, let's assume the following example:

```
@interface MyClass
@end
```

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void)internalMethod {
}

@end
```

```
@interface MyClass (SomeFunctionality)
@end
```

```
@implementation MyClass (SomeFunctionality)

-(void)someMethod {
  //WARNING HERE!
  [self internalMethod];
}

@end
```

My solution is to split the class into two parts:

```
@interface MyClass
@end
```

```
@implementation MyClass
@end
```

```
@interface MyClass (Internal)

-(void)internalMethod;

@end
```

```
@implementation MyClass (Internal)

-(void)internalMethod {
}

@end
```

And include `MyClass+Internal.h` from both `MyClass.m` and `MyClass+SomeFunctionality.m`

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well just call `[[MKStoreManager class] performSelector:@selector(storeKitItems)];`, right?  (This doesn't address rmaddy's concern that it's a bad idea to do this because a change to a private method could break the category.)

Comment: @AaronBrager Well, that was only the first part of my answer :)

Comment: @AaronBrager It is not in general sufficient to use `performSelector:`.  The compiler must see a declaration of the message because the message's type signature affects the code the compiler must generate to send the message.  And if you're going to declare the message anyway, you might as well just send it directly instead of using `performSelector:`.

Answer (score 0):

In you category implementation file you can define and informal protocol for the method

```
@interface YourClasses (ExternalMethods)

+(NSDictionary*) storeKitItems;

@end
```

This will stop the compiler from complaining about not knowing of the method storeKitItems in you category.